# Error in installing the plugin in localhost in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I am trying to install the existing .zip file by using the upload plugin button.
But I am getting error. I tried by making uploads directory in wp-content

```
/wp-content/uploads

sudo chmod 0777 {path_of the file}/wp-content/uploads
```

but still, I am getting the same error.

error is

```
Unable to create directory wp-content/uploads/2020/10. Is its parent 
directory writable by the server?
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0dLKf.png)

Comment: This site is for programming-specific questions. Questions about WordPress administration, server configuration, etc. are off topic and are more suited to the [dedicated WordPress Development Stack Exchange site](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com).  However please review their help section first before posting to make sure your question meets their guidelines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of using upload plugin you can try to extract the files directly into the plugins directory. Just copy your zip file in :
wp-content>plugins and right click and extract hear.

This should work...